# What value to set alert for load on AWS EC2 instance?

Tags: amazon-ec2, monitoring

We are using EC2 instances and are monitoring the server usage.

Right now the main metric we are looking at is idle CPU:  [Monitoring load on AWS EC2](https://serverfault.com/questions/430948/monitoring-load-on-aws-ec2/431916?iemail=1#431916)

However, I am also hoping to monitor "load" as measured by the `top` command.  We are running on large instances, so it appears to us as if we have 2 cores.

For fully owned servers, I usually set the trigger value to slightly higher than the number of cores (e.g. if 2 cores, trigger an alert if the load is over 2.5 for more than a minute).  Is this still the right thing to do on EC2?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After finding out that load measures correctly for each user on EC2, we went with our standard load triggers.

For us that is half a CPU above the max for more than 5 minutes.